# KeyError:'' Empty String Error Pyspark (Spark RDD)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am doing a simple exercise to recommend new friends based on a mutual friend edge-list graph, computing the top 20 mutual friends of every particular user subject to some filter conditions.
I am using Spark RDD to perform this task.

I have below the edgelist in all_friends, which stores the friend list edges as a key value pair. The graph is undirected, so for every `('0', '1')`, `('1', '0')` also appears,

```
    all_friends.take(4)
[('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '3')]
```

So part of my code contains the following:

```
    from collections import Counter
results = all_friends\
    .join(all_friends)\
    .filter(filter_conditions)\
    .map(lambda af1f2: (af1f2[1][0], af1f2[1][1]))\ #at this point each entry has form [(k,(v1,v2)], hence the lambda expression
    .groupByKey()\
    .mapValues(lambda v: Counter(v).most_common(20))
```

However, after the map I get a KeyError, noted below. This also occurs if I put a `.keys().collect()` right after the map. This is strange, as I am unsure why spark is looking for the key '' (empty string) when it clearly does not exist in my original rdd. I'm not sure if it has to do with the full outer join. Could someone advise?

```
 An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 78.0 failed 3 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.2 in stage 78.0 (TID 291, 100.103.89.116, executor 5): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 367, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 390, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-155-140ba198945e>", line 2, in <lambda>
KeyError: ''
```

Comment: Put your chained calls into separate calls in separate lines so you can see which call is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

filter_conditions looks incorrect. here is a working code with pseudo filter code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from collections import Counter

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Python Spark').set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

all_friends = spark_session.sparkContext.parallelize([('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '3')])


# [('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '3')]

# print(all_friends.take(4).collect())

def filter_conditions(c):
    if c[0] == '1':
        return c


results = all_friends.join(all_friends).filter(filter_conditions).map(
    lambda af1f2: (af1f2[1][0], af1f2[1][1])).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda v: Counter(v).most_common(20))

print(results.collect())
```

**output**

```
[('3', [('3', 4), ('0', 2)]), ('0', [('3', 2), ('0', 1)])]
```